# AWS Code Deploy Issue Service: error during start or run: Net in Server 2016 AMI

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

```
I am trying to use ci/cd in .net framework on window server 2106 AmI  I have installed the cloud deploy agent on window server also attach IAM profile in eC2 also configured on service role

When I am trying to deploy the apps on window server  the cloud deploy agent gave me this error ::
```

Error : - Code Deploy Instance Agent Service: error during start or run: Net::OpenTimeout - execution expired - C:/Windows/TEMP/ocr424E.tmp/lib/ruby/2.3.0/net/http.rb:880:in `initialize'

Comment: Got the same error. I was able to fix it after running InitializeInstance.ps1 script as suggested below. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codedeploy-net-opentimeout-errors/

Answer (score 0):

actually i was used to custom ami for this server .

Resolution will be

1. take the snapshot of this ami
2. create an image of this ami ...
3. after the create  a new instaner and run ec2 instalize command on that server after that i have sucessfully done the deployment on that server .